# How to encourage stealing of gifts in a white elephant gift exchange?

Tags: party

I am arranging a white elephant gift exchange game. In previous years, guests were too polite, refusing to steal gifts from others, so the game amounted to nothing more than people choosing a number from a hat and then choosing a gift from the table in the order of their numbers. Are there any steps I can add to the game to motivate people to overcome their politeness?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a board game.

Comment: But it is playable on a table, has rules, offers dynamic challenges, and is playable by hand!

Answer (score 4):

That's simple. Get two secret gifts worth at least as much as the exchange. At the end of the exchange, everyone votes for the most devious steal. Both the thief and the victim get one of the surprise gifts.

And great times were had by all!